# Capture error information from SSL_CTX_set_verify

Tags: c++, ssl, callback

I've edited this question to more directly ask for the information I'm looking for.

In this callback function:

int verify_cert_chain_callback(int ok, X509_STORE_CTX *store)

I'd like to determine which SSL* or SSL_CTX* it originally came from...or was generated from. Is there a way to get that information?

I'm looking for something similar to this feature request, which would add an application-defined argument to be supplied to the callback function, but for "SSL_CTX_set_verify()"

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2929

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It  is unclear what you are asking. What means "capture to log"? Log is usually very similar to console output.

Comment: I want to capture the error information and hold it in memory so I can log it later or on a different thread. There may be multiple simultaneous socket connections so I need to be able to capture the error information and associate it with the appropriate socket for later logging.